# Implement Apect-oriented-like nested around filters with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, filter, aop

I'm trying to write a class that supports nested around filters without introducing an Aspect-oriented library.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :around_filter

  def initialize
    #filters which wrap the following one are the ones with interesting logic
    #vanilla do-nothing filter
    @around_filter = lambda { yield } # or lambda {|&blk| blk.call}
  end

  def bar
    #would execute the around filters however deeply nested, then "meaty code"
    @around_filter.call do
      #meaty code here
      puts 'done' 
    end
  end

  #I expected to point only to the topmost filter, hoping to recurse
  def add_around_filter(&blk)
    prior_around_filter = @around_filter
    @around_filter = #??mystery code here?? refers to prior_around_filter
  end
end
```

The goal is to be able to add any number of around filters:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.add_around_filter do
  puts 'strawberry'
  yield
  puts 'blueberry'
end
foo.add_around_filter do
  puts 'orange'
  yield
  puts 'grape'
end
foo.bar #=> orange, strawberry, done, blueberry, grape
```

I know there are a bunch of holes in the example.  I wrote only enough to covey the general direction, distilling from a much larger actual class.

Although I prefer `yield` syntax, I'm not opposed to block references:

```
foo.add_around_filter do |&blk|
  puts 'orange'
  blk.call
  puts 'grape'
end
```

I got this working only with a single around filter.  I tried lots of things with nesting, but never cracked the puzzle.  If you have a solution, I'd appreciate it a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yield` in your filters will try to yield to the block defined at the point of their definition, which is not what you want. It will work with the explicit block form (in 1.9) as follows:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :around_filter

  def initialize
    #filters which wrap the following one are the ones with interesting logic
    #vanilla do-nothing filter
    @around_filter = Proc.new{|&blk| blk.call }
  end

  def bar
    #would execute the around filters however deeply nested, then "meaty code"
    @around_filter.call do
      #meaty code here
      puts 'done' 
    end
  end

  #I expected to point only to the topmost filter, hoping to recurse
  def add_around_filter(&filter)
    prior_around_filter = @around_filter
    @around_filter = Proc.new do |&blk|
      filter.call do
        prior_around_filter.call(&blk)
      end
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.add_around_filter do |&blk|
  puts 'strawberry'
  blk.call
  puts 'blueberry'
end
foo.add_around_filter do |&blk|
  puts 'orange'
  blk.call
  puts 'grape'
end
foo.bar #=> orange, strawberry, done, blueberry, grape
```

Comment: That little bit of code was quite elusive.  A huge thanks, Marc-André!  A big help!

Comment: It's amazing what a big impact the very subtle block semantics changes in Ruby 1.9 have.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to explicitly specify the "before" and "after" part of each filter:

#### Code

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @before_filters = Array.new
    @after_filters = Array.new
  end

  def bar
    @before_filters.each { |f| f.call }
    puts "done"
    @after_filters.each { |f| f.call }
  end

  def add_filters(options)
    @before_filters.insert(0, options[:before])
    @after_filters << options[:after]
  end
end
```

#### Usage example

```
>> foo = Foo.new
>> foo.add_filters(:before => lambda { puts "<body>" },
                   :after => lambda { puts "</body>" })
>> foo.add_filters(:before => lambda { puts "<html>" },
                   :after => lambda { puts "</html>" })
>> foo.bar
<html>
<body>
done
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually my current implementation, but unfortunately I have a need whereby the around_filter is a better fit.  Thanks, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it in ruby 1.8.X mimicking Rack's behavior with middlewares:

```
class Builder
  def initialize
    @filters = []
    @app = nil
  end

  def add_filter filter
    @filters << proc { |app| filter.new(app)}
  end

  def run app
    @app=app
  end

  def build
    app = @app
    @filters.reverse.each do  |filter|
      app = filter.call(app)
    end
    @app = app
  end
  def go(env)
    build
    @app.call(env)
  end
end


class FilterBase
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    puts ">>> BEFORE"
    @app.call(env)
    puts "<<< AFTER"
  end
end

class FilterSecond
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    puts "<hello>"
    @app.call(env)
    puts "</hello>"
  end
end

class FilterThird
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env[:feeling]=:happy
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

class DummyApp
  def call(env)
    puts "HELLO #{env.inspect}" 
  end
end


b = Builder.new
b.add_filter FilterBase
b.add_filter FilterSecond
b.add_filter FilterThird
b.run DummyApp.new
b.go({:feeling => :bad})
```

Will lead to

```
>>> BEFORE
<hello>
HELLO {:feeling=>:happy}
</hello>
<<< AFTER
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an AOP library like [aspector](http://github.com/gcao/aspector), then you can save a lot of boilerplate code, plus you can test the aspect separately. Without using any library, below code will do what you want

```
class A
  def bar input
    puts input
    input.upcase
  end

  def self.add_around_filter target, &block
    @filter_count ||= 0
    @filter_count += 1
    filter_method = "#{target}_around_filter_#{@filter_count}"
    define_method filter_method, block

    orig_method = instance_method(target)
    define_method target do |*args, &block|
      send filter_method, orig_method.bind(self), *args, &block
    end
  end
end

A.add_around_filter :bar do |proxy, *args, &block|
  puts 'before'
  result = proxy.call(*args, &block)
  puts 'after'
  result
end

A.add_around_filter :bar do |proxy, *args, &block|
  puts 'before 2'
  result = proxy.call(*args, &block)
  puts 'after 2'
  result
end

puts A.new.bar 'abc'

# Output
#before 2
#before
#abc
#after
#after 2
#ABC
```